# Why are these two expected values equal?

Tags: probability-distributions, proof-explanation, machine-learning, expected-value, regularization

This question refers to section 13.2 in Chapter 13, "Regularization and Stability", from the book "Understanding Machine Learning: From Theory to Algorithms", which can be found in a PDF version [here](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf):

How are the two expected values equal in the proof of the theorem in the red box below?

By their definitions:

$$\ \Bbb E_{S \text{ ~ } D^m, z' \text{ ~ } D}[l(A(S), z')] = \Bbb E_S[\Bbb E_{z'}[l(A(S), z')]] = \Bbb E_S [\sum_{z' \in Z}l(A(S), z')D(z')]$$

$$ \Bbb E_{S \text{ ~ } D^m, z' \text{ ~ } D}[l(A(S^{(i)}), z_i)] = \Bbb E_S[\Bbb E_{z'}[l(A(S^{(i)}), z_i)]] = \Bbb E_S [\sum_{z' \in Z}l(A(S^{(i)}), z_i)D(z')]$$

But for these to be equal we must have:

$$ \sum_{z' \in Z}l(A(S), z')D(z')= \sum_{z' \in Z}l(A(S^{(i)}), z_i)D(z')$$

I can't see how these are equal.

Anyone have any ideas?

---

[image]

Comment: What are $L$, $\ell$, $A$?

Comment: $L$ is error with $L_D(h)$ being general error and $L_S(h)$ being empirical error, $l$ is a loss function, and $A$ is a learning algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid I completely misunderstood the question the first time because of the notation, and therefore deleted my first answer, which was fundamentally wrong.

From my understanding, since all of the points $z_1,...,z_m,z'$ are chosen in an i.i.d fashion, then training an algorithm on any $m$ points from them and then testing on the other remaining point will result in the same expected loss regardless of which point we chose. For all relevant $i$, $z_i$ and $z'$ are symmetrical in that sense: they are both drawn from the same probability distribution in an independent manner, and therefore it doesn't matter which point we include in the training set and which point we test on. The equality in the red box that you marked refers exactly to that.

In addition, note that the expected values in both sides of the equality depend on $S$ as well, which contains that point $z_i$, and not just $z'$, which is implied by what you wrote in the first paragraph.

Comment: But if $$ \sum_{z' \in Z}l(A(S), z')D(z')= \sum_{z' \in Z}l(A(S^{(i)}), z_i)D(z')$$ then that means: (Left) the sum of the losses of each point times the point's probability is equal to (right) the loss on just the point $z_i$ times the probability of every point $z' \in Z$.  That means the RHS equation becomes $l(A(S^{(i)}), z_i) \sum_{z' \in Z}D(z') = l(A(S^{(i)}), z_i)$ since it's a single point loss and $\sum D(z') = 1$.  How can the loss on all points from some set be the loss of a single point?

Comment: @OliverG I don't see how the expression you wrote in the comment refers to the equality in the red box.
Also, as I mentioned before in the deleted answer, equality in expectation doesn't mean that the two random variables are always equal, so I'm not sure where you got that expression from.

Comment: I derived the expression in the third equation in my question.  It is the result of applying the definitions to both sides of the equality in the red box.  Repeated here, they're these results that I asked in my question.  $$\ \Bbb E_{S \text{ ~ } D^m, z' \text{ ~ } D}[l(A(S), z')] = \Bbb E_S[\Bbb E_{z'}[l(A(S), z')]] = \Bbb E_S [\sum_{z' \in Z}l(A(S), z')D(z')]$$

$$ \Bbb E_{S \text{ ~ } D^m, z' \text{ ~ } D}[l(A(S^{(i)}), z_i)] = \Bbb E_S[\Bbb E_{z'}[l(A(S^{(i)}), z_i)]] = \Bbb E_S [\sum_{z' \in Z}l(A(S^{(i)}), z_i)D(z')]$$  If these two are equal than their $\Bbb E_S$ arguments are equal.

Comment: @OliverG No, again that's where you're wrong. Two random variables can have the same expectation but entirely different arguments.

Comment: Then if they're different, why is their expectation equal?

Comment: @OliverG You should go over the basic definition of expectation. For example, let $X$ to be a constant random variable getting the value $0.5$, and $Y$ be a Bernoulli variable with $p=0.5$, and you get $E[X]=E[Y]=0.5$, even though the two variables are clearly different.

Comment: I understand the definition of expectation, but I don't see how the expectation with respect to all subsets of a sum of errors on different points is equal to the expectation with respect to all subsets of a sum of errors on a single point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89156/discussion-between-dean-gurvitz-and-oliver-g).